# 'addEventListener' of null error

Tags: javascript

I have this error with the `addeventlistener` function in javascript. I have 3 files index.html, movie.html and app.js. I got list of movies from an api. Once I click on the movie details button on the index.html file I want to redirect to the movie.html file and get the details of the movie using the movie-id from the api, but am getting the following error:

> app.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Does anyone knows that the be might causing my problem?

app.js file

```
document.getElementById("searchForm").addEventListener("submit", loadMovies);

function loadMovies(e) {
    let input = document.getElementById("searchText");
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=b94d8dbb7dcd23af16414e00a058c9ad&language=en-US&query=${input.value}`, true);
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            let movies = document.getElementById("movies");
            movies.innerHTML = "";
            let res = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            res.results.forEach(function (movie) {
                movies.innerHTML += `
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="card bg-dark text-center">
                            <div class="card-block">
                                <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${movie.poster_path}" class="img-fluid">
                                <h4>${movie.title}</h4>
                                <a onclick="movieSelected('${movie.id}')" href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="movie">Movie Details</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                `;
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Movie not found");

        }

    }

    xhr.send();

    e.preventDefault();
}


function movieSelected(id) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('movieId', id);
    window.location = 'movie.html';
    return false;
}


function getMovie() {
    let movieId = sessionStorage.getItem('movieId');
    // Make a request for a user with a given ID
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieId}?api_key=b94d8dbb7dcd23af16414e00a058c9ad`)
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            let movie = JSON.parse(response.data);
            Console.log(movie)
        }
    }
}
```

movie.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">MovieInfo</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div id="movie" class="well"></div>
</div> 

<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javacript">
    getMovie();
</script>
```

index.html

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="jumbotron bg-dark">
      <h3 class="text-center">Search For Any Movie</h3>
      <form id="searchForm">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchText" placeholder="Search Movie....">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="movies" class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That might be exactly what the error message tells you: `document.getElementById("searchForm")` doesn't exist at the time you're trying to refer it.

Comment: Your form might not have been loaded when your JS code is executed. You need to wait until the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Wait until the DOM has been loaded before you target the form element.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById("searchForm").addEventListener("submit", loadMovies);
});
```

The browser will execute your JavaScript as it encounters it: which is before it encounters the `<body>` tag. Therefore at this point trying to get a references to that element yields `null`.

So you have to find a way to way until the document has been loaded. One way is to put your scripts at the bottom of the body, another way is to wrap your code in an event handler triggered when the browser has loaded the document: [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) is the standard event.

Comment: Then please post the error and line number (from the relevant JS file)

Comment: this is the error i got after replacing my code with the one you suggested above  " app.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at app.js:2 "

Comment: Are you sure you are loading the script in the same page as the HTML? Try to post your while code on jsfiddle

Comment: i have 2 html files, index.html and movie.html. the app.js file is inside the body of both html files

Comment: hi, here is the link to the code on fiddlejs , i don't know how to add more than one html file, i added the index.html and app.js codes .am using the site for the first time.    https://jsfiddle.net/baezl/szg69ghy/     .. thanks